# Button doesn't called OnPointerDown() method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I decided to learn Unity by modifying Pacman game [tutorial](https://noobtuts.com/unity/2d-pacman-game) on desktop become Android game. For now, I tried to replace the input key from arrow key to UI button on my sprite script. And then drag the button as to the sprite input field.
[here is the input field image on my sprite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTO1x.png)

Bellow code supposed to be execute when I pressed my button. However, the button seems doesnt trigger any method.

```
if (rightButton.IsInvoking("OnPointerDown")){
                Debug.Log("OnPOinterDOwn() method is called");
```

Here is the complete code for my sprite :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PacmanMove : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed = 0.4f;
    Vector2 dest = Vector2.zero;

    public Button rightButton;
    public Button leftButton;
    public Button upButton;
    public Button downButton;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        dest = transform.position;
    }

     //Update is called in fixed time interval
    void FixedUpdate() {
        //Move closer to Desstination
        Vector2 p = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, dest, speed);
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().MovePosition(p);

        //Check for input if not moving
        if ((Vector2)transform.position == dest) {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow) && valid(Vector2.up))
                dest = (Vector2)transform.position + Vector2.up;
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow) && valid(Vector2.right))
                dest = (Vector2)transform.position + Vector2.right;
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow) && valid(-Vector2.up))
                dest = (Vector2)transform.position - Vector2.up;
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow) && valid(-Vector2.right))
                dest = (Vector2)transform.position - Vector2.right;

            //Bellow code supposed to be trigger when my UI button is pressed
            if (rightButton.IsInvoking("OnPointerDown")){
                Debug.Log("OnPointerMethod() is called");
            }
        }

        // Animation Parameters
        Vector2 dir = dest - (Vector2)transform.position;
        GetComponent<Animator>().SetFloat("DirX", dir.x);
        GetComponent<Animator>().SetFloat("DirY", dir.y);
    }

    bool valid (Vector2 dir) {
        //Cast line from 'next to Pac-Man' to 'Pac-man'
        Vector2 pos = transform.position;
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Linecast(pos + dir, pos);
        return (hit.collider == GetComponent<Collider2D>());
    }
}
```

Could somebody enlighten me what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing more tutorial, I have solve this problem. Turn out I must called Event Trigger on my button.
I also write another script attached to the button where it will be called from Event Trigger and set the boolean input on the sprite.

I elaborate more on [my medium post](https://medium.com/@andrea8787/pacman-for-android-with-unity-573c1b8a28a6).